# extending the apostrophe-blog module: template not found

Tags: javascript, apostrophe-cms

Trying to follow the suggested flow for [creating multiple blogs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apostrophe-blog) on my Apostrophe instance, creating new modules by extending `apostrophe-blog`. I *think* I'm doing the extending right: I have `staff-faculty-blog` in `lib/modules`, configuring all three of them in `app.js`, and my app runs. I go to add a new page using the type, and `template not found: pages/staff-faculty-blog-page.html` is given.

My question is, what am I doing wrong? lmao. I'm not quite understanding why it's searching for that name instead of how `apostrophe-blog` works -- which uses index and show files. At first I'd copied the views over into the `staff-faculty-blog-pages`, didn't work then so I took em out. Still didn't work.

Here's some code:

```js
//staff-faculty-blog/index.js

module.exports = {
    name: 'staff-faculty-blog',
    alias: 'staff-faculty-blog',
    label: 'Article',
    extend: 'apostrophe-blog',
};
```

```js
//staff-faculty-blog-pages/index.js
module.exports = {
    name: 'staff-faculty-blog-page',
    label: 'Staff & Faculty Blog',
    extend: 'apostrophe-blog-pages'
};
```

```js
//staff-faculty-blog-widgets/index.js    

module.exports = {
  label: 'Blog Widget',
  extend: 'apostrophe-blog-widgets'
};
```

```js
//app.js
var path = require('path');

var apos = require('apostrophe')({
  shortName: 'fun-with-apostrophe',
  bundles: ['apostrophe-blog'],
  modules: {
    'apostrophe-pieces-import': {},
    'apostrophe-blog': { contextual: true },
    'apostrophe-blog-pages': {},
    'apostrophe-blog-widgets': {},
    'staff-faculty-blog': { contextual: true },
    'staff-faculty-blog-pages': {},
    'staff-faculty-blog-widgets': {},
    'apostrophe-templates': { viewsFolderFallback: path.join(__dirname, 'views') },
    'apostrophe-pages': {
      filters: {
        ancestors: {
          children: {
            depth: 2
          }
        },
        children: true
      },
      types: [
        {
          name: 'default',
          label: 'Default'
        },
        {
          name: 'apostrophe-blog-page',
            label: 'Blog'
        },
        {
          name: 'staff-faculty-blog-page',
          label: 'Staff & Faculty Blog page'
        },
        {
          name: 'home',
          label: 'Home'
        },
      ]
    },
    'apostrophe-workflow': { alias: 'workflow' }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `name` option when configuring `new-blog-module-pages`, and set it to `new-blog-module-page`, so it doesn't just try to use `apostrophe-blog-page`.

`name` specifies what the `type` property of the index pages will be, in Apostrophe's database.

It would be nice if Apostrophe inferred this.

Comment: ohhhh _that's_ what you meant by that part. Okay, I'll do that.

Comment: hm, okay i'm still confused. is `name` in index not the same `name` that's in the config in app.js? 'Cause I've already given it a new name. Am i extending these properly?

Comment: Actually, your examples don't match up. You have new-module-blog-pages as a folder, versus staff-faculty-blog-pages in app.js.

Comment: yeah i actually wrote this confusingly here. all the names are correct: the name of the module is `staff-faculty-blog`.

Comment: I think you'd better share a sandbox project that demonstrates the issue so we can talk about apples and apples (: